# Are PermissionsMixin and PermissionRequiredMixin the same?

Tags: python, mixins, django-2.0

I want to know if `PermissionsMixin` has the same function as `PermissionRequiredMixin`.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionMixin
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin
```

Comment: No. The `PermissionMixin` is a mixin for *models*, whereas the `PermissionRequiredMixin` is a mixin for views (and some other objects).

Comment: Thanks! @WillemVanOnsem Van Onsem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No**, `PermissionsMixin` is a mixin for models, `PermissionRequiredMixin` a mixin to mix in views.

> I want to know if `PermissionsMixin` has the same function as `PermissionRequiredMixin`.

These are *not* functions, but *classes*. The `PermissionsMixin` is a mixin for *models*.

The [**`PermissionsMixin`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.PermissionsMixin) is a mixin for Django models. If you add the mixin to one of your models, it will add fields that are specific for objects that have permissions, like `is_superuser`, `groups`, and `user_permissions`. It also provides a set of utility methods to check if the model with this mixin has a given permission (for example with [**`has_perm`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.PermissionsMixin.has_perm). A typical model that subclasses this mixin is the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model).

The [**`PermissionRequiredMixin`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin) mixin on the other hand is a mixin that provides a convenient way to *check* if the user that is logged in, has the required permission(s). For example:

> ```
> from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin
> class MyView(PermissionRequiredMixin, View):
> permission_required = ('polls.can_open', 'polls.can_edit')
> ```

Here we thus define a `View`, but only users with these permissions, can access the view.

This mixin implements a `get_permission_required()` method that generates an iterable of permissions to check, and a `has_permission()` that checks if the user has these permissions. You can override these methods, for example if the permissions are *dynamic* (depend on the data in the database for example).

Answer (score 0):

To make it easy to include Django’s permission framework into your own user class, Django provides PermissionsMixin. This is an abstract model you can include in the class hierarchy for your user model, giving you all the methods and database fields necessary to support Django’s permission model.

> [PermissionsMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.PermissionsMixin)